# Java - Trouble creating a 2D array from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a text file that is formatted as a square array.  I am trying to convert this to a 2 dimensional array in Java.  "st" is the text file described below.

This is my code:

```
public createArray(String st) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

InputStream is;

is = new FileInputStream(st);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    int row = 0;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        String[] nums = line.split(" ");

        for (int col = 0; col < nums.length; col++){

            int n = Integer.parseInt(nums[col]);

            myArray[row][col] = n;
        }
        row++;

    }
```

I am getting a null pointer exception on the line:

```
myArray[row][col] = n;
```

If I print out the values of row, col, and n at each iteration, they appear to coincide correctly. However, I am still getting a NullPointerException.

The text file is formatted as:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 0
```

Comment: i doubt this Integer.parseInt(nums[col]) may throw NPE.

Comment: show how you have declared `myArray` ?

Comment: myArray is an instance variable and is declared as int[][] myArray;

Comment: How do determine the number of rows and columns stored in the file?

Comment: My problem was that I did not initialize myArray with any size declaration before populating it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have not initialized `int[][] myArray;`

You should do something like this

```
int[][] myArray = new int[100][100];
```

OR

find the total rows in the file and initialize the row. And in each loop calculate the column and create the desired array

```
int[][] myArray;
{
    int rows = getTotalRows();
    myArray = new int[rows][];
}
```

then

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        String[] nums = line.split(" ");
        myArray[row] = new int[nums.length]; //initialize dynamically here
        for (int col = 0; col < nums.length; col++){

            int n = Integer.parseInt(nums[col]);

            myArray[row][col] = n;
        }
        row++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Regards to your comment you didn't initiate array.

```
int[][] myArray = new int[100][]; // enough to define rows
```

Other way:

If you use  Java 7 you can load text file to `List`. As I know this is a shortest way to create `String[][]`

```
String[][] myArray;

List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("<your filename>"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

myArray = new String[lines.size()][]; 

for(int i =0; i<lines.size(); i++){
  myArray[i] = lines.get(i).split("[ ]+"); // you can use just split(" ") but who knows how many empty spaces
}
```

Now you have populated `myArray[][]`